# Weird Leetcode Bug: Array.fill() vs new Array.from()

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I was working on [Leetcode Problem 1770](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-score-from-performing-multiplication-operations/) and ran into some weird behavior that I'm hoping someone can help me understand.

It's a dynamic programming problem that requires you to instantiate a 2-dimensional array of length `m`. Pretty straightforward.

What's weird is that my syntax for generating a 2D array causes the problem to fail, but an alternative syntax passes all tests. As far as I can tell the two lines output an identical result.

My syntax:

```
//  const m = 3

    let memo = new Array(m).fill(new Array(m).fill(-Infinity))
    console.log({memo})

//  stdout: {
//    memo: [
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ],
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ],
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ]
//    ]
//  }
```

Alternative syntax:

```
//  const m = 3

    let memo = Array.from(Array(m), () => Array(m).fill(-Infinity))
    console.log({memo})

//  stdout: {
//    memo: [
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ],
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ],
//      [ -Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity ]
//    ]
//  }
```

To my eye the output of the two is exactly identical. Yet one passes all tests and what doesn't. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are filling the array with the same `Array` instance. In the second case every row is a new `Array` because you provided a factory function.

```js
const m = 3;

let memo = new Array(m).fill(new Array(m).fill(-Infinity));

console.log(memo[0] === memo[1]); // true
```

```js
const m = 3

let memo = Array.from(Array(m), () => Array(m).fill(-Infinity));

console.log(memo[0] === memo[1]); // false
```

As a side note, you don't need to pass an `Array` as the first parameter of `Array.from`, an `ArrayLike` is enough:

```js
const m = 3

let memo = Array.from({ length: m }, () => Array(m).fill(-Infinity));

console.log(memo);
```